# Running angular js with webpack NPM along with php server (localhost:8080)

Tags: php, angularjs, apache, npm

```
    Failed to load http://local.com/test.php: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
 Origin 'http://localhost:9080' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I would like to run the npm server from the real domain , the same I have apache with php local.com , because I could not test the API calls without be on the same URL

Answer (score 0):

Because of [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) you need to explicitly declare which agents are allowed access to resources on a different origin domain.

Your NPM server is on the localhost:9080 domain and it's trying to access resources on the localhost domain. They don't match.

The easiest way is set your PHP to send the header:

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:9080`

Which means that the resource can be accessed by the localhost:9080 domain.

Not recommend in production however, and if this is the architecture you desire, I would recommend looking at [Apache Module mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html) which will allow you to have an alias which seemingly proxies to your NPM server.